# Find the name of the employees with a particular letter

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm having the schemas like:

```
Employee (Empno, Empname, City)
Project (Pno, Pname)
Part (Partno, Partname, Color)
Use (Pno, Partno)
Works (Empno, Pno)
```

From these schemas I had created a sample tables:

The goal is to find the names of the projects where no employees are working whose name starts with 'S'

I'm using ORACLE 11g Express Edition.
Here I used this query :
For Names:

```
Select DISTINCT Pname FROM
(
SELECT w.Empno, p.Pno, p.Pname, e.Empname
FROM Works w
LEFT JOIN Project p ON w.Pno=p.Pno
LEFT JOIN Employee e ON e.Empno=w.Empno
)
WHERE Empname not like 'S%';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think about how to explain the process. There are several methods to solve this including:

1. You would start with each of the `Projects` and find out if there does not exist anybody who `Works` on the project where the `Employees` name starts with `S`. You can do this using `NOT EXISTS`.

or

2. Again, start with a `Project` and find, if any, who `Works` on the project and their corresponding `Employees` details using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s (but starting from the `Project`) and filtering for employee names starting with `S` in the `JOIN` condition. Then `GROUP BY` the primary key for the project and find those projects `HAVING` a `COUNT` of zero matched employees.

Since this appears to be a homework question, I'll leave the rest for you to complete.

Comment: @Hames You are finding the projects where there is any one employee with a name that does not start with `S` when you should be finding the projects when all the employees have names that do not start with `S` (or conversely where no employees start with `S`). Additionally, you are starting with the `Works` table and then left joining the other two when you should be starting with the `Project` table.